# Unfamiliar Structure of Sphere Mesh

Tags: mesh

I was poking around in a cycles material test scene which I donwloaded, and when I looked at the mesh for the sphere, it looked like this:

[image: Strange mesh pattern]
This looks nothing like either the UV sphere or the ICO sphere, so what function would transform the mesh into something like this?

Comment: There's no *function* to create meshes except for pre-made ones (primitives like what's in `Shift`+`A` menu, etc.) You should add a primitive and know how to edit it in order to get result you'd like to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a subdivided icosphere, generated from a basic icosphere via a subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

Of course the blender logo was then carved out of it via a boolean modifier.

Comment: Aha, I feel like an idiot for not noticing that earlier.

Comment: Happens to me all the time :)